# EZ Sheets Python credentials-sheets.json

Tags: python, google-sheets

Does the credentials-sheets.json file and two tokens for drive and sheets need to be in the same folder as my python script, or can they reside somewhere else on my machine.

For example, I've got a test.py file on my desktop and ezsheets works correctly if the json file and two tokens are also on the desktop.

Do I need to copy/paste these files into the same folder as my python project, or is there somewhere else I can store them where ezsheets will find them? It seems kind of redundant to have to copy paste them every time, but I'm currently in my first coding class so perhaps I don't know best practices.

Answer (score 0):

It's ideal if you can have the JSON file in the same folder, but not required. I'm unfamiliar with `ezsheets`, but I think it will work anywhere if you specify the correct file type. You should put the JSON file and the two tokens in the same folder (but not required).

For adding the file in the same folder, you can make use with the `sys` module.

```
import sys
path = sys.argv[0]
```

The path variable will have the script path. You can use this knowledge to determine the other files' path.